# LineageOS with Goclever devices

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, lineageos

Is it possible to have LineageOS on **Goclever Quantum 350**?

Are system requirements for LineageOS high? I mean can I run Android 6 or 7 on my device.

With CyanogenMod 12.1 it worked with Android 5.1.1

I saw the list of supported devices http://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/ but my device Goclever Quantum 350 is not flagship like Samsung Galaxy or Google Nexus and has 256MB RAM only.

Here are specs of this smartphone http://www.gsmchoice.com/en/catalogue/goclever/quantum350/Goclever-Quantum-350.html

Comment: If it's not listed there, you should probably search on xda-developers.com for ROMs and experiences if and how it runs...

Comment: No matter how hard you find, 256MB RAM is simply not enough for *anything* beyond KitKat. Trust me, even 512MB devices struggle.

Comment: You can try searching on xda, but 256mb doesn't work well even on kit-kat it could but it probably won't. So no, your device can't run android 6.0.x or 7.x, even if someone make custom rom you wouldn't be able to do much with it.

Comment: @Andy but I have 5.1.1 lollipop with Cyanogenmod 12.1 and works fast :) started with Jelly Bean 4.2.2

Comment: Depends on how you define "fast" - once you used some devices a tier above it, there's no turning back. Even though MT6572 is a dual-core SoC, it still is hampered by that amount of RAM. Anyway, as for the original question, if nothing turns up in search results, you're out of luck - development on MTK devices are scarce, not to mention MT6572 itself is very old.